# How to pass the dynamic value in Body data in the Post Request using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I recorded the .JMX script in Jmeter and one of the request is as below

POST http://www.hello.com/auth/nqa/md/login

Body data:
{"domainId":"nqa","code":"12345skdkdk"}

I would like to send the "code" field dynamically and for that I added the regular expressing extractor as below enter image description here
[image]

[image]

When i re run the script , the code value is not replaced with the dynamic value.

Not sure what part i am missing in the regular expression extractor or in the Body data field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First of all, you cannot extract the value from the **request body** using the Regular Expression Extractor, normally you should extract the dynamic values from the **previous** response so inspect the whole flow using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and look for your "code" value there
2. Your regular expression extractor in its current configuration will return **random** value in the parentheses so it could be `domainId`, `nqa`, `code` or `12345skdkdk`. Going forward if you need to get some dynamic data from JSON go for [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide)

Comment: i rechecked the requests and responses again thanks

Answer (score 6):

- List item

you should do three-step of below

1. go to the random variable according below picture
   [image]
2. Define random variable name . in this case we set variable name to code1 and set min & max value to this

[image]

3. Use ${code1} variable to your data section

[image]